# Need to duplicate onepage checkout inside the checkout module

Tags: magento, magento-1.3

I need to duplicate the onepage checkout function in CE 1.3.3 and want to be able to access it via domain.com/index.php/checkout/onepage-variant in order to be able to customize onepage without disturbing the core onepage checkout files.  This is is already in a dev environment and creating another store is not an option.

What would be the best way to approach this?

And advice will be greatly appreciated!

Edit:  Just to clear things up further what I need is 2 functioning instances of onepage checkout.  We're going to be doing testing based on 2 different customizations and see which one works best.

Comment: New routes = cheap & easy. OPC = big & complex. Can you provide any further details?

Comment: @benmarks Yes what Ive done is created a copy of the onepage.phtml and named it onepage-variant.phtml. Is it possible to create a route to go to this new phtml file using the url "http://magentostoredomain.com/index.php/checkout/onepage-variant/" ?

Comment: @benmarks Actually I finally got what I wanted by creating a new CMS Page labelled "Onepage-Checkout" and inserting layout xml for the onepage checkout with amendments to point to the duplicate phtml files and the onepage-variant template folder.  I can now customize the variant phtml files without disturbing the core onepage checkout. I can access my variant using SEF url.  Thanks for your input!